# How do I create (and display) a pdf page from a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, printing, pdf-generation

I am trying to decide if I can cope with the fact that Silverlight does not support printing.  One option is to create a pdf page that the user can then print.

How practical is this?

(I don’t know match about Siverlight yet, I am trying to decide if it is an option for the application before I start learning it in detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a product called SharpShooter by Perpetuum Software:
http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter-for-Silverlight.aspx

It produces PDFs, Word docs and images.  It is does require server components however.