# Printing in Silverlight2

Tags: silverlight, printing

(This must be a FAQ, but I can’t find any other questions about it.)

What are the options for coping with the lack of printing support in Silverlight?

**Other questions I asked trying to solve the same root problem.**

- [How do I create (and display) a MS-Word document from a Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433948/how-do-i-create-and-display-a-ms-word-document-from-a-silverlight-application/1435327#1435327)
- [Are there any client side report writers for Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433976/are-there-any-client-side-report-writers-for-silverlight/1435324#1435324)
- [How do I create (and display) a pdf page from a Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433928/how-do-i-create-and-display-a-pdf-page-from-a-silverlight-application/1435312#1435312)

---

**This has now changed with newer versions of Silverlight**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post has some good details on how you can implement printing in silverlight

http://jonas.follesoe.no/PrintingInSilverlight2UsingCSSAndASPNETAJAX4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but [David Poll's CollectionPrinter](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/04/16/making-printing-easier-in-silverlight-4/) seems very good indeed.